# Python pandas best way to store dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with thousands to entries like the following:
[Dataset Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdoqA.png)

```
row
1 timestamp type    side    strength    amor    health
2 23958722  robot_1 left    100         20      100
3                   right   200         25      100
4           robot_2 left    100         25      90
5                   right   80          10      19
6           robot_3 right   40          20      200
7           robot_4 left    100         100     20
8 1424121   robot_1 left    90          19      100
9           robot_2 left    90          25      10
```

My questions:

1. Is it possible to transfer this data into a pandas DataFrame?
2. Will I have to store the timestamp 23958722 (row 2) also for row 3 to 7?
3. Do I have to provide the right side in timestamp 1424121 for robot_1 and robot_2?
4. Is it possible to avoid providing the robot_1 (row 2) again in row 3?

I'm also somewhat stuck with how I could set the index here. One query could be for example: Get the health values of all robot_1 on the right. Which should only return row 3.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Generally `pandas` can do anything :) But how do you have the dataset stored now? There are many `read_???` functions in `pandas` that get data from different data sources. And most of the time it reads it perfectly, without need for fine-tuning the parameters.

Comment: I have a test dataset stored now for testing in excel. A tiny section I posted. But actually the data comes just in time from a server every second or so a new row.

Comment: Is your source data Excel? If so, it looks like a starting point could be: `df = pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx', index_col=[0, 1, 2])`... Then you can use advanced indexing to select values (eg: `df.xs(('robot_1', 'right'), levels=('type', 'side'))`... or if you want things expanded out do `df.reset_index()`...

Answer (score 0):

1- Use DataFrame.shift() method to shift an index

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'t': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'Mid Elec': [0., 43102.5, 41692.0, 40592.8], 'South Elec': [0., 43102.5, 41692.0, 40592.8], 'North Elec': [0., 43102.5, 41692.0, 40592.8]})
df.set_index('t', inplace=True)
df = df.shift(-1)
```